# Trying to submit form with Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a form that has all these fields and they all have required validators attached to them.

My goal is to have the user enter the form and if he fills out last name and hits submit the form will still postback to save the lastname but the other 3 fields will show an error message saying "blah blah blah"

Basically I need to validate the form but even if the form fails I would just like to display an error summary but still submit the valid fields if any.

```
<input runat="server" id="LastName" type="text" name="LastName"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvLastName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please type last name" ControlToValidate="LastName">Last Name Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   

<input runat="server" id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName"/>
<required first Name>
<input runat="server" id="MiddleName" type="text" name="MiddleName"/>
<required middle name>
<input runat="server" id="EmailAddress" type="text" name="EmailAddress"/>
<required emailaddress>



 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#forminfo').validate({
            rules: {
                LastName: {
                    required: true
                },
                EmailAddress: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },     
            messages: {
                LastName: "Please enter your last name",
                EmailAddress: "Please enter a valid email address"        

            }
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You could set `EnableClientScript=false` and call `Page.Validate()` yourself in codebehind, can't you?

Comment: setting enableclientscript to false turns off validation all together I don't want to turn off validation if the fields are invalid I would still like to show the error message but also save the values that were valid

Comment: The errors would still be visible after the postback but the postback will still happen with disabled client validation.

Comment: do you mind showing me a small sample not sure what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to explain what [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) suggested.

In the markup set `EnableClientScript = "false"`:

```
<input runat="server" id="LastName" type="text" name="LastName"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvLastName" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="Please type last name" ControlToValidate="LastName">Last Name Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   

<input runat="server" id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName"/>
<required first Name>
<input runat="server" id="MiddleName" type="text" name="MiddleName"/>
<required middle name>
<input runat="server" id="EmailAddress" type="text" name="EmailAddress"/>
<required emailaddress>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

I have added a submit button. In the code, button's event handler, validate page like below:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        //Do other tasks
    }
    else
    {
        //Do tasks even if validation fails
    }
}
```

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: THis makes sense that is what I have I think it is not working for me because of my javascript code that I use to validate also. Is there a way i could do this same approach with the javascript validation?

Comment: If you use javascript validation plugin, after postback error messages will be lost.